# Install Ubuntu 20 PV guest on a Debian 10 Xen

Tags: ubuntu, debian, xen, pv

Struggling to find a guide to do this. I've understood that `xen-tools` supports installing Ubuntu guests on Debian so that should be a fast and easy way but can't find any examples.

Anybody knows a good guide to help me? Is it mandatory to use HVM for installation?

Answer (score 0):

Figured out in the end, it seems that `xen-create-image --dist=focal [...]` is available in the latest `xen-tools` version so you can go with `debootstrap` installation method. However, Debian 10 has an older version which only supports Ubuntu up to 19.

So, the easy thing to do is install `xen-tools` from sources as this is just a simple collection of scripts: https://github.com/xen-tools/xen-tools.